# SQL Server allocating values from specified rows to other rows on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with customer-level data for which a large number of rows do not have assigned values in the customer field, but do have values in the sales field. I would like allocate the sales dollars in these rows with "unassigned" customers to rows with customers, and I would like to complete this allocation in proportion to the sales already allocated to named customers. Finally, I would like to delete the rows with unassigned customers from my table. For example, my data looks roughly like:

```
     Year     Market       Customer       Sales
     2016     China        A              100
     2016     China        B              150
     2016     China       Not assigned    200
     2015     Europe       D              100
```

In the above example, I would like the sales value in the third record to be allocated to rows 1 and 2 (where year and market are equal to row 3) in proportion to their sales figures. Thus, the final table should look like:

```
    Year    Market     Customer    Sales
    2016    China       A          180
    2016    China       B          270 
    2015    Europe      D          100
```

To start, I've created a new table with each "not assigned" rows, grouped by the relevant dimensions for the allocation.

```
 SELECT *
 INTO [dbo].[notassignedtable]
 FROM(
     SELECT YEAR, Market, Customer, sum(Sales) as Sales
     FROM table
     WHERE Customer = 'Not assigned'
     GROUP BY YEAR, Market, Customer
  ) grouped
```

Is this a step in the right direction? Having trouble with where to go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: This is in SQL Server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT   *,
    [Sales] + ([Sales] / SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN [Customer] <> 'Not assigned'
      THEN [Sales]
      ELSE 0
    END) OVER( partition BY [YEAR], Market) * SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN [Customer] = 'Not assigned'
      THEN [Sales]
      ELSE 0
    END) OVER( partition BY [YEAR], Market)) AS result
  FROM Yourtable
  ) a
WHERE [Customer] <> 'Not assigned'
```

This is used to find the contribution of each each customer

```
[Sales] / Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] <> 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market)
```

This is used to find the amount that is not assigned

```
Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] = 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market))
```

Multiply the contribution with not asiggned amount

```
([Sales] / Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] <> 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market) 
                   * Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] = 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market))
```

Then add with original sales to get the result

```
[Sales] + ([Sales] / Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] <> 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market) 
                   * Sum(CASE WHEN [Customer] = 'Not assigned' THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) OVER( partition BY [Year], Market)) AS result
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/HFOXOI42669)